# Postfix dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (mail transport unavailable)

Tags: postfix-mta

On my Postfix server on my own local machine, I want to set up my Titan Mail account (james707@externalemail.org) as my relayhost. Despite me setting up the Titan Mail SMTP settings, when I send an email from my local account (james707@testemail.org) to my test GMail account (james707@gmail.com), I keep getting this following error:

```
Aug 29 01:12:10 james707-PC postfix/smtps/smtpd[256675]: warning: dict_nis_init: NIS domain name not set - NIS lookups disabled

Aug 29 01:12:10 james707-PC postfix/smtps/smtpd[256675]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]

Aug 29 01:12:12 james707-PC postfix/smtps/smtpd[256675]: 993C6176049F: client=localhost[127.0.0.1], sasl_method=PLAIN, sasl_username=james707

Aug 29 01:12:12 james707-PC postfix/cleanup[256685]: 993C6176049F: message-id=<1e8ff91b-e6d0-41e8-9a9e-fd66a8784e69@testemail.org>

Aug 29 01:12:12 james707-PC postfix/qmgr[1860]: 993C6176049F: from=<james707@testemail.org>, size=581, nrcpt=1 (queue active)

Aug 29 01:12:12 james707-PC postfix/qmgr[1860]: warning: connect to transport private/[smtp.titan.email]: No such file or directory

Aug 29 01:12:13 james707-PC postfix/error[256686]: 993C6176049F: to=<james707@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=0.58, delays=0.39/0.01/0/0.17, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (mail transport unavailable)

Aug 29 01:12:18 james707-PC dovecot: imap(james707)<4491><i/GS6ckDzMp/AAAB>: Disconnected: Logged out in=130206 out=487184 deleted=0 expunged=0 trashed=0 hdr_count=0 hdr_bytes=0 body_count=0 body_bytes=0

Aug 29 01:12:19 james707-PC dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<james707>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=256690, TLS, session=<u4V6sQkENq9/AAAB>

Aug 29 01:12:20 james707-PC dovecot: imap(james707)<256690><u4V6sQkENq9/AAAB>: Disconnected: Logged out in=286 out=1734 deleted=0 expunged=0 trashed=0 hdr_count=1 hdr_bytes=257 body_count=0 body_bytes=0
```

Here are my settings:

/etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)

biff = no

append_dot_mydomain = no

readme_directory = no

compatibility_level = 3.6

smtp_use_tls=yes

smtpd_use_tls=yes

smtp_tls_cert_file=/home/james707/Documents/ssl-certs/server.pem

smtp_tls_key_file=/home/james707/Documents/ssl-certs/server.key

smtpd_tls_cert_file=/home/james707/Documents/ssl-certs/server.pem

smtpd_tls_key_file=/home/james707/Documents/ssl-certs/server.key

smtp_tls_wrappermode=yes

smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes

smtp_tls_security_level=encrypt

smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt

smtp_tls_CApath=/home/james707/Documents/ssl-certs/cacert.pem

smtpd_tls_CApath=/home/james707/Documents/ssl-certs/cacert.pem

smtp_tls_protocols=TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3

smtpd_tls_protocols=TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3

myhostname = testemail.org

virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual

transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport_maps

myorigin = /etc/mailname

mydestination = $myhostname, testemail.org

mynetworks =

sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_relay

mailbox_size_limit = 0

recipient_delimiter = +

inet_interfaces = all

inet_protocols = all

queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix

smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes

smtp_sasl_password_maps = static:james707@externalemail.org:pass1234

smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous

smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt

header_size_limit = 4096000

relayhost = smtp.titan.email:465
```

/etc/postfix/virtual:

```
james707@testemail.org james707
```

/etc/postfix/transport:

```
testemail.org   relay:[smtp.titan.email]:465
```

/etc/postfix/sender_relay:

```
james707@testemail.org     [smtp.titan.email]:465
```

/etc/postfix/master.cf

```
#

# Postfix master process configuration file. For details on the format

# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master" or

# on-line: http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html).

#

# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.

#

# ==========================================================================

# service type private unpriv chroot wakeup maxproc command + args

# (yes) (yes) (no) (never) (100)

# ==========================================================================

smtp inet n - y - - smtpd

#smtp inet n - y - 1 postscreen

#smtpd pass - - y - - smtpd

#dnsblog unix - - y - 0 dnsblog

#tlsproxy unix - - y - 0 tlsproxy

# Choose one: enable submission for loopback clients only, or for any client.

#127.0.0.1:submission inet n - y - - smtpd

submission inet n - y - - smtpd

-o syslog_name=postfix/submission

-o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt

-o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes

# -o smtpd_tls_auth_only=yes

# -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no

# -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions

# -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions

# -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions

# -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=

-o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject

# -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING

# Choose one: enable smtps for loopback clients only, or for any client.

#127.0.0.1:smtps inet n - y - - smtpd

smtps inet n - y - - smtpd

-o syslog_name=postfix/smtps

-o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes

-o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes

-o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject

-o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject

-o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot

-o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth

# -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps

# -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes

# -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes

# -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no

# -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions

# -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions

# -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions

# -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=

# -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject

# -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING

#628 inet n - y - - qmqpd

pickup unix n - y 60 1 pickup

cleanup unix n - y - 0 cleanup

qmgr unix n - n 300 1 qmgr

#qmgr unix n - n 300 1 oqmgr

tlsmgr unix - - y 1000? 1 tlsmgr

rewrite unix - - y - - trivial-rewrite

bounce unix - - y - 0 bounce

defer unix - - y - 0 bounce

trace unix - - y - 0 bounce

verify unix - - y - 1 verify

flush unix n - y 1000? 0 flush

proxymap unix - - n - - proxymap

proxywrite unix - - n - 1 proxymap

smtp unix - - y - - smtp

relay unix - - y - - smtp

-o syslog_name=postfix/$service_name

# -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5

showq unix n - y - - showq

error unix - - y - - error

retry unix - - y - - error

discard unix - - y - - discard

local unix - n n - - local

virtual unix - n n - - virtual

lmtp unix - - y - - lmtp

anvil unix - - y - 1 anvil

scache unix - - y - 1 scache

postlog unix-dgram n - n - 1 postlogd

#

# ====================================================================

# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual

# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.

#

# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery

# agent. See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}

# and other message envelope options.

# ====================================================================

#

# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.

# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1

#

maildrop unix - n n - - pipe

flags=DRXhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}

#

# ====================================================================

#

# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.

#

# Specify in cyrus.conf:

# lmtp cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4

#

# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:

# mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost

# virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost

#

# ====================================================================

#

# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)

# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1

#

#cyrus unix - n n - - pipe

# flags=DRX user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}

#

# ====================================================================

# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.

#

#old-cyrus unix - n n - - pipe

# flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}

#

# ====================================================================

#

# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.

#

uucp unix - n n - - pipe

flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)

#

# Other external delivery methods.

#

ifmail unix - n n - - pipe

flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)

bsmtp unix - n n - - pipe

flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient

scalemail-backend unix - n n - 2 pipe

flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}

mailman unix - n n - - pipe

flags=FRX user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py ${nexthop} ${user}
```

I have gone through various websites, tried many potential solutions, but nothing has worked so far.